# How can i broadcast my factory result to other controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to broadcast my result from one controller to another, I have a IntroController where i call article Service factory. after getting response from article factory i want to broadcast its result to Article Ctrl (article controller) but i am unable to broadcast the result to Article Ctrl (article controller).

```
// Intro Ctrl code here

    angular.module('starter.controllers')
    .controller('IntroCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate,$q,articleService,$rootScope) {
          articleService.getArticles().then(function(res) {
             $rootScope.$broadcast('articleFetch', res);
              $scope.$emit('articleFetch', res);
            }, function(err) {
                alert("error");

            });

    });

// articleService factory code here


angular.module('starter.controllers')
.factory('articleService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
            getArticles: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: "my-link.com/secure-mobile/getallinfo?access_token=b8fa2380632307d58834d037d7dc65fc",
                    data: { starLimit: 0, endLimit: 100,created_date: 0 },
                    method: 'POST',
                    withCredentials: true,
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (err) {
                 deferred.resolve(0);
                })
                return deferred.promise;
            }

    }
});
```

I want to broadcast this articleService result(i.e res) to ArticleCtrl controller.

```
 // ArticleCtrl code here

    angular.module('starter.controllers')
      .controller('ArticleCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {
          alert("fff");
            $rootScope.$on('articleFetch', function (event, args) {

                    alert(args);
            $scope.articles = args;

            });
     });
```

when i call $rootScope.$on in ArticleCtrl then i am not getting alert.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to broadcast your event 
and into your second controller `$scope.$on` to catch the event

It seems that you did it properly.
However, for this to work, both controllers MUST be already loaded.

**Is it the case ?** 
If not, then you can't catch an event into a non existing controller ;)

Comment: I am not sure.  how to check if controllers are already loaded or not.

Comment: add an alert at the begining of your second controller. if you have your alert, then the controller is loaded.

Comment: i am using ionic Framwork. i added alert on that controller and refresh the page. nothing happens . when i called that controller that function triggers

Comment: this means that when you are on the page that where you want to pass your service datas, then your second controller is not loaded. 
To help you solve your case, you need to add more information on your pages workflow, what $state your are when you call your service, what $state you need to be after , etc...

Comment: i am on intro State,  where i get that for Broadcasting and going to article state on click event